# Polynomial Division and roots of Unity

Tags: polynomials

I cannot answer something. I have to find the smallest positive integer n so that the polynomial $g(x)=x^{11} + x^{10} + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1$ over $Z_2[x]$ divides the polynomial $(x^3 - 1)^n$. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please take a look at [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about formatting your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: Given that $x^3-1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$, and those two factors are irreducible, it looks like you need to start factoring $g(x)$. If you can write $g(x)$ in the form $(x+1)^k(x^2+x+1)^\ell$, then $n$ is the maximum of $k$ and $\ell$. Do you see why? If no such factorization exists, then neither does $n$.

Comment: Hint: $g(x)$ has seven terms (unless you missed one while typing), so can it be divisible by $x-1$?  I really think there is a typo here, but if there isn't then the question is easy.

Comment: How can i factorize this polynomial over Z2? g(x) has seven terms yes

Comment: You don't need to directly factor $g(x)$. Since by hypothesis, $g(x)$ is a divisor of $(x^3-1)^n$, any irreducible factor of $g(x)$ must also be an irreducible factor of $x^3-1$, so that constrains the factored form.

Comment: The exact question has to do with codes also. I have to find the smallest positive integer n so that the polynomial generator of Golay code G23( that is g(x)) divides the polynomial (x^3 - 1)^n. Then I have to describe the code that is generated by (x^3 - 1)^n.

Answer (score 1):

Following Jyrki Lahtonen's hints . . .

Since $Z_2$ is a field, $Z_2[x]$ is a UFD.

Identically, $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Of course, the factor $x-1$ is irreducible in $Z_2[x]$.

The factor $x^2 + x + 1$ is also irreducible in $Z_2[x]$, since it's quadratic and has no roots in $Z_2$.

It follows that the unique factorization of $(x^3-1)^n$ in $Z_2[x]$ is
$$(x^3-1)^n = (x-1)^n(x^2+x+1)^n$$
Since $g(x)$ divides $(x^3-1)^n$ in $Z_2[x]$, then in $Z_2(x)$,
$$g(x)h(x) =(x^3-1)^n = (x-1)^n(x^2+x+1)^n$$
for some $h \in Z_2[x]$.

But then by unique factorization, the factored form of $g(x)$ in $Z_2[x]$ must be 
$$g(x) = (x-1)^a(x^2+x+1)^b$$
for some nonnegative integers $a,b$.

Since $\deg(g)=11$, we must have $a+2b=11$, so $a$ must be odd, hence $a > 0$.

But $a>0$ implies $g(1)=0$, contradiction, since direct substitution into the specified expanded form of $g$ yields $g(1) = 1$.

Comment: Exactly :-) ${}$

Comment: Thank you very much for this!!!